# Better way to separate different values in arrays in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 for plotting data from serial port

Serial data is in the form given below(X type and Y type)

**27Y 27Y 12X 0X 25Y 26Y 153X 214X 29Y 28Y 29Y 28Y 139X 154X 249X 196X 0X 2X 27Y
27Y 25Y 25Y 26Y 26Y 175X 242X 26Y 27Y**

I am using following code for separating the data and store in two different arrays:

```
 # Read from serial port, blocking
 data =ser.read(1)
 data1=(data)


 # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
 n = ser.inWaiting()
 data1 = (data1 + ser.read(n))
 l = data1.split( )

 x = [d.strip("X") for d in l if d[len(d)-1] != "Y"]
 y = [d.strip("Y") for d in l if d[len(d)-1] != "X"]



 for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
    del a2[i]


 for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
    del a4[i]


 a2.extend(x)


 a4.extend(x)
```

Above code is only part of complete code required for separating the values

**Is there some better and more faster way to separate the values of X type and Y type and store in different arrays.**

Thanks

Comment: What are `a2` and `a4`?

Comment: a2 = deque([0.0]*384) , a4 = deque([0.0]*384)

Comment: Are you trying to keep the length of `a2` constant? Your current code increases the length of `a2` by 1, since you `del` `len(x)-1` items, but extend by `len(x)` items.

Comment: If your goal is to keep the length constant, you can easily achieve this by using the `maxlen` argument to the `colections.deque` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The downside of the list comprehensions here is that you iterate over `l` twice, whereas you could do it once:

```
x = []
y = []
for d in l:
    if d.endswith("X"):
        x.append(d[:-1])
    else:
        y.append(d[:-1])
```

The explicit slice may be slightly quicker than `strip`, as it doesn't need to check the first or penultimate characters of the string. You could then do e.g.

```
a2 = a2[len(x):] + x
```

rather than deleting one item at a time.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `collections.deque` with a max length to keep the length of some sequence constant.  (I'm guessing that's the actual intention.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'd say that's worth a separate answer